# Tally database synchronization with c# Application

Tags: c#, sql-server, odbc, erp

I want to make an application to sync Tally `Sales Order` and `Sales Invoice` from tally to our SQL Database.  Currently for testing purpose I am using `Tally ERP 9 Educational Version`.

I have created some sales orders in tally and need all order with their details from tally using `tally ODBC Sql query`

uptil as per my research, I am getting few sales order details like `Voucher Number`,`Order Date`,'Voucher Type'.. etc. from tally ODBC table `CompanyVoucher`. but few details came empty, although related data exist in tally order. like `Reference` , `Party Name` ... etc.

Also, I am unable to find `Tally ODBC table` to get few other sales order related data like `item name, item number , item quantity, rate and order total, order no` etc.

Can anybody suggest `SQL Query` or `Tally ODBC Table` from where i can find these order related data. Also I am not sure, if we can not access these details due to `Educational Version`, and any limitations on `Educational Version` on access of these details.

so please suggest me on this.

Comment: Have you tried using SSIS to import the data from Tally? If you right click on your database in SQL Management Studio and click on Tasks -> Import Data, you can select the source as Tally ODBC Driver. When you click on Next it will give you a list of tables I presume. You can find out from here what tables are available as sources, then choose which columns you want to import.

Comment: @sagar did you get success in your integration, if yes then please post an answer to your question so that other community members can get benefited.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronisation is the process of replicating data between two or more computers using Tally.ERP 9 in a Client – Server environment. Data is transferred from the client to the server and vice versa. Tally.ERP 9 offers control over the frequency of Synchronisation i.e., data can be replicated after each transaction or updated at specific intervals.

Configure Server for Synchronization

To configure the Server Company for Synchronization, follow the steps given below:

Go to Gateway of Tally > F12: Configure > Advanced Configuration

In the Advanced Configuration screen,

Under Client/Server Configuration section,
Set the option Tally is acting as to Server, to run Tally.ERP 9 as Sync Server
Specify the required port number (e.g. 9009) in the Port field....

Tab down to Tally Sync Configuration section:

Set the option Ignore Clients modified Voucher Type Masters to No, so that modifications made to Voucher Type Masters on the Client are updated on the Server

Set the option Enable Sync Logging to Yes, to generate a Log file which contains synchronized vouchers and is saved in the Tally folder.

Set the option Truncate previous log before Syncing should be set to Yes, to allow the previous log file to be overwritten by the current log file.

Go to end and press Enter to save the details.

For the above changes to take effect, Tally.ERP 9 will prompt you to restart the application as shown:

Press Enter or select Yes to restart Tally.ERP 9 on the Server computer. 
Tally.ERP 9 will restart and in the Information Panel you can see that it is configured as the Sync Server as shown below.

Detailed reference [here](http://ask.enggforum.com/79/how-to-synchronize-data-in-tally&show=80#a80).

> If the datas are present and you cannot access the sync then there
>   must be restriction in your version